# JavaScript Function Object Parameter Assert

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameters, assert

Implementing asserts in code to check passed function parameters for validity, I resulted in a situation, when parameter can be initialized with no object, undefined therefore. The problem is that asseting it as undefined is not always an error and I don't want to see it in the log.

Is there still a sense of asserting object parameters then? Can there be any other values of this parameter, I should bother to assert and include in my error log?

```
function(store, records, success, eOpts) {
  console.assert(
      records,
      "Error - no records passed to function." // Could be no records, no object passed. Its ok!
  );
}
```

Comment: `undefined` *is* not an object. If you want to allow that, simply change your assertion. Please show us the code you have so we can suggest you how to do that.

Comment: the code is of no case, but I added; this relates to a general approach for asserts anywhere in any code; about undefined - an important notice that was; but still the question remains - we have parameter value undefined, where object is expected; sometimes this is ok; should be check this parameter at all in this case?

Comment: If it's ok then I see no reason to check it? You might as well place the assertion in that code branch where an object is expected.

Comment: I doubt that nothing else can be checked. Therefore I've asked the question. At least the type of parameter can be checked to be an object, not a string, or something else?

Comment: Well of course if you know that it must be "object or undefined", you can simply check for that.